# MongoDB Ingest ETL Design Options

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pymongo, etl, logstash

I'm a total newb when it comes to MongoDB, but I do have previous experience with nosql stores like *Hbase* and *Accumulo*.  When I used these other nosql platforms, I ended up writing my own data ingest frameworks (typically in java) do perform ETL like functions, plus inline enrichment.

I haven't found a tool that has similar functionality for Mongo, but maybe I'm missing it.

To date I have a [**Logstash**](http://logstash.net/) instance and collects logs from multiple sources and saves them to disk as `JSON`.  I know there is a [**mongodb output plugin**](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/outputs/mongodb) for Logstash, but it doesn't have any options for configuring how the records should be indexed (i.e. aggregate documents, etc).

For my needs, I would like to create multiple aggregated documents for each event that arrives via Logstash -- which requires some preprocessing and specific inserts into Mongo.

Bottom line -- before I go build ingest tooling (probably in python, or node) -- is there something that exists already?

Answer (score 1):

Try [node-datapumps](https://github.com/agmen-hu/node-datapumps), an etl tool for nodejs. Just fill the input buffer from JSON objects, enrich data in .process() and use a [mongo mixin](http://agmen-hu.github.io/node-datapumps/docs/mixin/MongodbMixin.html) to write to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho ETL have good support of Mongodb functionnality.

You can have a look at http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDB+Output

Answer (score 0):

I just found one ETL tool Talend Open Studio, it has support for many file formats . I just uploaded multiple xml files on MongoDB using Talend. It also is backed by a Talend forum where many Q & A can be found.